# Fade Custom View

Tags: android, animation, alpha, fading

I'm trying to write my own implementation of `Toast` class.

toast_layout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toast_layout_root"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="@android:drawable/toast_frame"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:text="This is a toast!" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then I try to fade in and out it:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();            
View toast = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout,               
    (ViewGroup) this.findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));                                                                                                

long fade_duration = 1000; // milliseconds                         

AlphaAnimation fadeInAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);         
fadeInAnimation.setDuration(fade_duration);                        
toast.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation);                             

AlphaAnimation fadeOutAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);        
fadeOutAnimation.setDuration(fade_duration);                       
fadeOutAnimation.setStartOffset(fade_duration + Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setAnimation(fadeOutAnimation);
```

But nothing appear then. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for response.

Comment: where is your toast.show() ?

Comment: @slymnozdmrc I don't use Toast class. I just create View and fade it.

Answer (score 0):

My personal util methods for fading views

```
public static void fadeIn(View view) {
    fadeIn(view, 500);
}

public static void fadeIn(View view, long millis) {
    view.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(millis).start();
}

public static void fadeOut(View view) {
    fadeOut(view, 500);
}

public static void fadeOut(View view, long millis) {
    view.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(millis).start();
}
```

you might also want to set it to GONE after that:

```
  public static void fadeOut(final View view, long duration, boolean hideAfter) {
        ViewPropertyAnimator animator = view.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(duration);

        if (hideAfter) {
            animator.setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                }
            });
        }
        animator.start();
    }
```

(if you do, remember to set it to VISIBLE next time when you fade in)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Toast customtoast=new Toast(context);   
    customtoast.setView(toast);-->yourtoast
    customtoast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL,0, 0);
    customtoast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    customtoast.show();
```

Add above code block after this below code.

```
    View toast = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout,               
   (ViewGroup) this.findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));
```

I hope this help you.Please see the reference.
http://www.androidinterview.com/android-toast-creating-a-android-custom-toast-example/